# First Fragment View not loading when navigate from third fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

Here when I landed to first fragment all views are loaded and scrolling but when I come from third fragment i.e from some other activity I need to land in third fragment,and when navigate to first fragment views are not loading which makes non scrollable.
Firstfragment xml contains recyclerview and Group elements.

MyActivity class:

```
    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);

        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

//MyAdapter

    public class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Fragment> fragmentList ;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm,List<Fragment> fragmentList) {
        super(fm);
        mContext = context;
        this.fragmentList = fragmentList;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return  fragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return mContext.getString(R.string.firstfragmentname);
            case 1:
                return mContext.getString(R.string.seconsfrag);
            case 2:
                return mContext.getString(R.string.thirdfrag);

            default:
                return null;
        }
      }
    }

//XML has custom viewpager
<ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/headerHeight"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/footerHeight"
            android:fadingEdgeLength="0dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp_30_60"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp_30_60"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/sp_header"
                    style="@style/pageTitle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/my_bill" />

                <com.view.Tab
                    android:id="@+id/tab_custom"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/tab_height" />

                <com.custom.CustomViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/sp_viewpager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp_10_53"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp_10_53"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

//CustomViepager

    public class CustomViepager extends ViewPager {

    public CustomViepager(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initPageChangeListener();
    }

    public CustomViepager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initPageChangeListener();
    }

    private void initPageChangeListener() {
        addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                requestLayout();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        View child = getChildAt(getCurrentItem());
        if (child != null) {
            child.measure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
            int h = child.getMeasuredHeight();
            heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(h, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        }
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    }

    @Override
    public void setCurrentItem(int item) {
        super.setCurrentItem(item, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void setCurrentItem(int item, boolean smoothScroll) {
        super.setCurrentItem(item, false);
     }
    }
```

Comment: Use FragmentStatePagerAdapter instead of FragmentStateAdapter

Comment: Wh do you need a custom view pager

Comment: @LakhwinderSingh If i don't use CustomViewpager with onMeasure overriding then not able to see layout it's totally blank screen.

Comment: what do you think will happen if you dont use custom view pager, because i did not understand tha use of  onMesuare, can you please specify

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple view pager and Try to use it like this

CustomPagerAdapter

```
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter

class MyPagerAdapter(fm: FragmentManager, behaviour: Int) : FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm, behaviour) {

    private val mFragmentList = ArrayList<Fragment>()

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        return mFragmentList[position]
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return mFragmentList.size
    }

    fun addFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment)
    }


}
```

In Activity/Fragment

```
private var mAdapter: MyPagerAdapter? = null
```

in `onCreate`

```
mAdapter = MyPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), FragmentStatePagerAdapter.BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT)
mAdapter?.addFragment(YOUR_FIRST_FRAGMENT)
mAdapter?.addFragment(YOUR_SECOND_FRAGMENT)
mAdapter?.addFragment(YOUR_THIRD_FRAGMENT)

sp_viewpager.offscreenPageLimit = 3
sp_viewPAger.adapter = mAdapter
```

When you want to land on the desired position, after the above code write

```
sp_viewpager.setCurrentItem(1/2/3,true/false)
```

Answer (score 0):

> [@LakwinderSingh answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56931833/10561553) to this question is perfect.

Just want to highlight one thing is that, the main trick or real problem is with the `offscreen page limit` it's the number of fragments the pager creates left or right to the current fragment, by default this value is one.

That's why when we scroll to the third Fragment it doesn't load anything cause loading the third fragment will require loading 2 fragments at the same time to the left, by changing the `offscreen page limit` value we can determine the number of fragments that load up at a specific time in this case which would be 2.

If we did above then we also have to override PagerAdapter's default function `destroyItem()` to an empty function without `super` so that there aren't too many fragments destroyed and created at the same time cause that would make sliding choppy or make fragments blank.